# How to query a class with custom __init__

Tags: django, django-queryset, initializer

I save my model's class into database and now trying to query it by using default manager's method .objects.all().

I get this error:

> **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Here is my model:

```
class BaseCrudEntity(models.Model):

    pass
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class BaseListViewPreset(BaseCrudEntity):
    RelativeClass = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True)    

    def __init__(self, context):
        BaseCrudEntity.__init__(self)
        self.model = context
        self.columns = []
        #self.setColumns(self.model)
        self.RelativeClass = ".".join([context.__module__, context.__name__])

    def addColumn(self, prop):
        _column = Column(system_name = prop.name, Preset = self)
        self.columns.append(_column)   

    def setColumns(self, context):
        _props = context._meta.get_fields()
        for prop in _props:
            self.addColumn(prop)

class Column(models.Model):
        system_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
        lookup_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
        Preset = models.ForeignKey(BaseListViewPreset, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

I have a record in database for Preset and several records for its columns.
The error i receive when calling BaseListViewPreset.objects.all()

I try to comment the **init** inside preset class and it helps me to *query* it. 
But I need init for initializing.

So how can I solve this problem?

The traceback is here:
http://dpaste.com/15449TR

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your `__init__()` must be compatible with that of `Model`'s. What are you actually trying to achieve with this design?

Comment: I just would like to create an instance of a class, then save it in my databae and then querry it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `BaseCrudEntity.__init__(self)` you should do `super().__init__()`

Comment: this is not working in such implementation. I am not sure about the true reason of this, because I am not an expert in django.
Anyway the problem is not in the super() or direct call parent initializer. This is not about calling the parent class. This is about init in this very class. I could comment all the body of the initializer, leaving just declaration of it and the error still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I finally understand something. But please check me if I wrong, because my background in programming is less than 1 month.

I have to create an instance of a class. Then I have to save it in my database, then query tables and, seriazlize response. Nothing special, just regular case.

My problem (except of lack of background) is that I try to overwrite init functions.
So please check me:

1. First, I have to create an instance of a class. For this purpose I have to call a build-in init function, right?
   `_preset = BaseListViewPreset()`
2. Second, I have to initialize a class properties with some values for the instance, created on previous step, right?. For these purpose I write a wrap for initializer, because I don't want to overwrite it (sending kwards arguments directly cause some wierds errors):

```
    def create(cls, context):
        _preset = cls()
        _preset.model = context
        _preset.RelativeClass = ".".join([context.__module__, context.__name__])
        return _preset
        pass
```

3. Third, I have to call this function from other part and save the instance:

```
            _preset = BaseListViewPreset.create(self.model)
            _preset.save()
```

4. Now I can query it by `.objects.all()`

Now this works as I expect(anyway there is some magic stuff for me about how django works). Is it alright, or this is ugly solution and I have to do it better? nad how then?